# Network dhcp discovering

Tags: dhcp

How can I scan all network computers have ip static or dynamic?

I've checked ip from all network but I don't how can check the dhcp settings.
It's possible this without access to the aserver?

Comment: what equipment? You can do DHCP snooping on a cisco switch

Comment: scan network using FingBox or Nmap, check against your DHCP leases. Dont know an automated way to check one against the other

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to check the DHCP server. If you don't have access sniff your network traffic using tcpdump / wireshark for some time (filter only DHCP traffic, otherwise you'll end up with lots of unnecessary data).  From this data you should get a pretty good list of DHCP clients in your network.

Answer (score -2):

You can always try an IP directed broadcast, e.g. in a 10.0.0.0/24 network it would be the last IP address of the network 10.0.0.255.

All hosts responding to ICMP will answer and the ones not in your DHCP server's IP range obviously have a static IP address assigned.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. When you do directed broadcast, all online devices in the subnet will answer, it doesn't matter if they have static IP address or dynamic. @JensLink has a good of scanning when you don't have access to DHCP server.

Comment: A directed broadcast is one that is initiated from a different network through a router. It used to be the default to allow directed broadcasts, but that is now just the opposite. Routers will not forward a directed broadcast unless they are configured to do so. Allowing a directed broadcast is a _huge_ security risk.